# Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express intellisense not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

**I tried googling, but I couldn't find a fix.**

Before, when writing:
console.writeline();, C# would automatically uppercase it to Console.WriteLine();.
Now, by mistake, I somehow deactivated that function.
 If I write console.writeline(), it doesn't turn it into Console.WriteLine();. Any ideas?

Comment: are you talking about this ? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/05/01/how-to-turn-off-automatic-intellisense-vstipedit0054.aspx and full info is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your looking for is called: *Intellisense*

The sole goal of this feature is to allow coding to be more productive, smarter, and easier.

You can renable *Intellisense* by hitting **CTRL + J**.  That will manually reactivate it.  Otherwise you'll need to go to:

- Tools
- Options
- Text Editor
- Auto List Member

But one of those should address your issue.  Otherwise I might suggest running a repair on Visual Studio or Restoring it back to defaults.  Cause by default it is enabled and configured correctly.

A known issue can also come from third-party Add Ons that actually handle such data can cause issues with *Intellisense* so uninstalling such Add Ons, then defaulting Visual Studio should fix it as well.

Example:

- Resharp
- Visual Assist X
- Just Code
- Etc.

Basically the ones that handle code completion, quick coding features.

Here is an article from [Microsoft Developer Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Hopefully that helps.